# Creating a table with each row containing a button that relates to the data of that row

Tags: php, html, ajax, html-table

I was wondering how I would be able to create a button that would be related to the information in that row.

So far I have an array that contains a person's first name, last name, and phone number. I would also like to create a button, so when the user clicks that the information of the person is carried to the next PHP page.

Should I be creating a form each time I create a row in the array?

So far I have:

```
foreach($array as $row)
        {
                echo (
                "<tr>".
                "<td>".$row['last_name'].       "</td>".
                "<td>".$row['first_name'].  "</td>".
                "<td>".$row['phone_no'].        "</td>".
                "<td>".$row['date_of_birth'].   "</td>".
                "<td>".$row['membership'].  "</td>".
                "<td><Button>Reserve</Button></td>".
                "</tr></table>");
        }
```

The reason it is being echoed is because I am using it in an ajax function and wish to output the result that way.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the new HTML5 data attribute for this:

```
<td><Button data-id='4'>Reserve</Button></td>
```

You can then use javascript, or more specifically [jQuery's .data() functionality](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to get this data value

**Edit**

```
<!-- Firstly give your button a class -->
<td><button class='ajax_button' data-id='4'>Reserve</button></td>
```

Then the Javascript

```
// On click for a button
$(".ajax_button").click(function(){

     // Get the id data attribute
     var id = $(this).data("id");
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Learned something new today!

Answer (score 0):

Html forms http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

you only need one form, with many inputs. if you want to do multiple data in the form you can just give it a name like `name='data[{n}][last_name]'` where {n} is an incremented number or the id of the row.

you will then have an array like `$_POST['data'][{n}][<fields>]` when you submit it

you also dont need the braces around your data to be echo'ed. `echo '<stuff>';` is fine